# Install postgresql with play! framework (Driver not found: [org.postgresql.Driver])

Tags: postgresql, playframework

I'm new with the play! framework and postgresql and I'm trying to make it work.

I read a lot of questions asked on stackoverflow and I searched a lot on google but I didn't manage to make it work.

Here is the error that Play! gives me :

```
Driver not found: [org.postgresql.Driver]
```

My questions are :

1) Do you know an easy tutorial (i.e. that explains from the beginning) that shows how to configure play! to make postgresql work? I read a lot of thing but didn't find a detailed tutorial.

2) If not, here is my configuration :

I added this in `application.conf` :

```
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1/postgres"
db.default.user=postgres
db.default.password=root
```

And in `built.sbt` :

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As the documenation says, you have to add the driver to your dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.2.12"
```

Use the appropriate version of the driver for your Postgres installation.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaDatabase

Comment: For the latest dependency version see: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql